# WMI class and instance for password policies

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi

what is the class and session name to get the password policy options through WMI bridge provider?  is there any property which can enforce the user to change the password if it is not matching the password complexity criteria.

Comment: As far as I know, there's no way to force a user to change insecure password. only by setting "change password on next logon" flag. But this setting should be set for every account individually.

Comment: @montonero   the following line can be used from AD point.   Set-ADUser -Filter * -ChangePasswordAtLogon:$true.   I heard some more settings can be possible to the password policy using MDM/WMI Bridge Scripting. But i have no idea how we can do that. any resources in terms of more properties in pass word policy chnage.